# Is this possible to play Video File synchronous downloading with Almofire?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, alamofire

I try to download file using `Alamofire` and I done that with progress. What I am trying to do now is building a type of local stream from video URL.

Alamofire store the downloaded file at destination.

```
let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .LocalDomainMask)
```

This destination is not valid to play in my case. eg.

```
if totalBytesRead >= 51831 {
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(destination)"))
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    self.presentViewController(playerController, animated: true) {
                                player.play()
                            }
}
```

Is there another way to do this ? OR can I store downloaded bytes to an array/buffer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Alamofire in order to stream content which is in your case a video.

You can actually utilize existing Apple's classes such as:

- [AVPlayerItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritem)
- [AVPlayerLayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayerlayer)
- [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer)

Using those 3 classes you can create your own class like VideoPlayer that will use them for streaming.

Here's a code snip for the constructor to get you started:

```
playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: videoURL)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
playerLayer?.frame = newFrame
playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
```

Now, you can use this class inside another View Controller:

```
self.containerView.layer.addSublayer(self.videoPlayer.playerLayer)
```

This will add the video player class you created and now you only need to play the video:

```
// Of type AVPlayer
player.play()
```

This is the easy part, if you want you will have to to implement your own buffer & rate and of course implement an observer to observe the rate and buffer:

```
 // Observe the Rate of the player. when the video playing or paused
 player.addObserver(theSelf, forKeyPath: "rate", options: .New, context: nil)
 // Observe when the Video player Buffer is empty
 playerItem.addObserver(theSelf, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options: .New, context: nil)
 // Observe the loaded Buffer of the video
 playerItem.addObserver(theSelf, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
```

Also, don't forget to remove them when you are done with them.

**EDIT:**

As asked, if you need to switch to a better quality during run time you will first need to observe the user's internet speed. After you solved this issue you will now need to stream the high quality video by for example adding another VideoPlayer layer on top of the current layer but only do it if your new high quality video buffer has at least 5 secs or so, so the user won't notice the change.

Good luck.

Comment: First thanks for your reply. 
I worked on AVPlayer. Actually I want to switch between two qualities, I have two urls of same  video with different qualities. I try to switch that locally without stalling in video playing like youtube. So i thought start playing with low quality and on internet speed switch to high quality which is pre downloaded. I think video quality switching on Youtube is my requirement. 
Any better solution or any suggestion how youtube do that.

Comment: If you need to switch you will first need to observe the user's internet speed. After you solved this issue you will now need to stream the high quality video by for example adding another VideoPlayer layer on top of the current layer but only do it if your new high quality video buffer has at least 5 secs or so, so the user won't notice the change.

Comment: yes thats very suitable solution for that. Now I have to maintain two AVPlayer + AVPlayerLayer instances and switch according to my requirements. 
Let me try that. I will come back with new progress.
Thanks a lot OhadM.

Comment: Thanks Alot OhadM. thats work for me. I will improve my solution further.